# jquery virtual keyboard - Curser not blinking in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, microsoft-edge, virtual-keyboard

I used the jQuery virtual keyboard, but I found a problem In chrome and Edge Browsers. when I click on the textbox, the cursor focuses not working, and am not able to see where am typing when editing the text. But In IE Browser its works well. am need to know why it's not working in Chrome and Edge browsers and how to resolve this issue. Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I created a simple example to test it, and it works normally, and the cursor can be displayed correctly in the input box.
This is my test demo (in Edge Version 91.0.864.48):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.30.3/css/keyboard-basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Enter something here:  <input type="text" name="name" contenteditable="true" id="enterBox" value="" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.30.3/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.keyboard.keyaction.undo = function (base) {
            base.execCommand('undo');
            return false;
        };
        $.keyboard.keyaction.redo = function (base) {
            base.execCommand('redo');
            return false;
        };

        $('#enterBox').keyboard({
            usePreview: true, // disabled for contenteditable
            useCombos: false,
            autoAccept: true,
            layout: 'custom',
            customLayout: {
                'normal': [
                    '` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - = {del} {b}',
                    '{tab} q w e r t y u i o p [ ] \\',
                    'a s d f g h j k l ; \' {enter}',
                    '{shift} z x c v b n m , . / {shift}',
                    '{accept} {space} {left} {right} {undo:Undo} {redo:Redo}'
                ],
                'shift': [
                    '~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + {del} {b}',
                    '{tab} Q W E R T Y U I O P { } |',
                    'A S D F G H J K L : " {enter}',
                    '{shift} Z X C V B N M < > ? {shift}',
                    '{accept} {space} {left} {right} {undo:Undo} {redo:Redo}'
                ]
            },
            display: {
                del: '\u2326:Delete',
                redo: '↻',
                undo: '↺'
            }
        });
            //.addTyping();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4qG9.gif

Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem? This will help solve the problem, thank you for your understanding.